# Specflow generated feature.cs file not working

Tags: specflow, generated-code, feature-file

*Last time it actually worked: Monday 27/07/2018*

I've been using specflow for around 2 years now. But as of today (this week) I've got an issue I never encountered before. When changing even a single letter in the .feature file as usual Specflow will regenerate the .feature.cs file. But there it's going wrong. The file becomes blank with just a single line which is a reference to my temp folder C:\Users\Me...

The thing about my username is that it's my real name and it contains a special character: "ë". Could there be a new bug introduced in the newest version from monday 6/08/2018? If so, is there a workaround while waiting for it to be fixed? Or is something entirely different going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest version of the Visual Studio extension which has problems with special chars in the username, because it's used in the path to the temp directory.

There is a post about it in the forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specflow/977_H2ICwT8).

The quickest way to workaround this, is to change the generation mode to AppDomain (Tools\Options\SpecFlow)
[image]

The better way is to switch to the MSBuild generation, as we will remove the AppDomain generation mode in the next months.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!